# Rails 5 in a docker container performing `rake db:setup` always loses connection to postgresql after first command is successful, using docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Rails 5, `docker-compose` project [(Github link)](https://github.com/fablabbcn/smartcitizen-api) which works fine with multiple containers.

I can create the database with with `docker-compose exec app rails db:create` and run the project on `localhost:3000`

The problem is that it always errors:
`could not connect to server: No such file or directory` after successfully completing the command.

This is a problem when I want to use the `db:setup` which performs 3 other commands. It completes the first command and then errors, saying the connection is lost, unable to perform the remaining 2 commands.

Is something closing the connection between the commands? How can I debug this further?

Rails 5.2.1, pg 1.1.3 [Gemfile](https://github.com/fablabbcn/smartcitizen-api/blob/master/Gemfile)

The `RAILS_ENV` is defined in an `.env` file. In this case it is:

```
root@3ec00f6534aa:/app# printenv|grep RAILS
RAILS_ENV=development
```

Here is the error output from within the app container, after performing `docker-compose exec app bash`.
Notice the second line, saying that the db was created:

```
root@b281e881b96a:/app# rake db:setup
Created database 'sc_dev'
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>10, "database"=>"smartcitizen_testing"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:684:in `connect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:215:in `initialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:40:in `new'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:40:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:809:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:853:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:832:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:793:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:521:in `checkout'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:380:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1008:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:12:in `connection'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:21:in `create'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:119:in `create'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:139:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:316:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:313:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:313:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:138:in `create_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running `rails db:create` without specifying an environment. Because of this, Rails tries to save you some effort and runs the command for both the development and test environments (I can’t remember which order they run in). You see that the `sc_dev` db is created, but then the error states that it couldn’t create the database for the `smartcitizen_testing` database.

Rails can connect to your development database, but not your test database.

After some comments back and forth, I learned that you are using the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, which is problematic because both the test and development databases do not actually share the same database url. The solution was to modify the `database.yml`, so that the development and test databases can be configured via environment variables independently, allowing them to each have their own settings when a single `rails db:create` command is run.

Comment: There are links to the repo in the post, but here is the [database.yml](https://github.com/fablabbcn/smartcitizen-api/blob/master/config/database.yml)

Comment: So, where is your Postgres installed? You aren’t specifying a host inside the database.yml file for the test environment like you are in development. I’m not sure of your Docker setup, and don’t know a ton about Docker. But what I do know is Rails, and Rails can’t find your test database.

Comment: Just so you know, Rails is currently expecting to find the test database inside the Docker container that the Rails app is running in because without a host configured in database.yml, it assumes localhost.

Comment: Now I mirrored the `development:` section into the `test:` section in `database.yml` (except for the `database:` name). And inside the container the `RAILS_ENV=development` is already set if I do `printenv`. If I prepend it to the command it still fails. It should only try to create 1 database (the dev one), right?

Comment: I am using `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to specify which database to connect to.
It looks like `dev` uses that, but `test` does not. Can that be the core issue?
Also: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21441

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. I usually just put my own environment variables in the the `database.yml` file and use them for the host and such. Maybe try giving that a shot? From what I'm seeing, trying to use `DATABASE_URL` will give you some troubles, if your development and test databases are not supposed to share the same `DATABASE_URL`. Are they supposed to?

Comment: No. I [added](https://github.com/fablabbcn/smartcitizen-api/commit/58f6464e272512d9e3b34029696fe899ffab115d) 2 ENV vars for `test` in `database.yml` to specify `host:` and `username:` and that fixed it. So the original problem was I was using `DATABASE_URL`, which does **not work** in `test`, because it would nuke your production db. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to update your answer and I will mark it as the solution?

Comment: Awesome! I’ve updated my answer to reflect our conversation.